# Unit Testing image.onload and image.onerror Inside React.useEffect() With Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, promise, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component which displays an image when it is fully loaded:

```
export default function ImageDisplay(props: OwnPropsInterface): JSX.Element {
    const { src, alt, height, width } = props;

    const [image, setImage] = React.useState<string>('');
    const [showImage, setShowImage] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
    const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = React.useState<string>('');
    const [imageWidth, setImageWidth] = React.useState<string>('');

    const setImageDimensions = () => {
        setImageHeight(
            typeof height === 'string' ? height : `${convertPixelsToRem(height)}rem`
        );
        setImageWidth(
            typeof width === 'string' ? width : `${convertPixelsToRem(width)}rem`
        );
    };

    const loadImageAsync = async () => {
        const image: HTMLImageElement = new Image();

        image.onload = () => {
            setImage(image.src);
            setShowImage(true);
        };
        image.onerror = (error) => {
            setShowImage(true);
        };

        image.src = src;
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setImageDimensions();
        loadImageAsync();
    }, [src]);

    return (
        <>
            {showImage && (
                <img
                    src={image}
                    alt={alt}
                    style={{ height: imageHeight, width: imageWidth }}
                />
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

I need to test `image.onload` and `image.onerror` and the subsequent behaviour of the component.

Currently I have the below test written:

```
    describe('ImageDisplay', () => {
        let useEffect: jest.SpyInstance;
        let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;

        const mockUseEffect = () => {
            useEffect.mockImplementationOnce((f) => f());
        };

        beforeEach(() => {
            useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementation(() => {});

            mockUseEffect();
            mockUseEffect();
            wrapper = shallow(<ImageDisplay {...imageDisplayProps} />);
        });

        describe('on load', () => {
            it('should set image props', () => {
                expect(wrapper.find('img').props()).toEqual({
                    alt: 'test_alt',
                    src: '/test/src',
                    style: {
                        height: '100%',
                        width: '100%',
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

The `expect` call fails with the below error:

```
Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

      115 |         describe('on load', () => {
      116 |             it('should set image props', () => {
    > 117 |                 expect(wrapper.find('img').props()).toEqual({
          |                                            ^
      118 |                     alt: 'test_alt',
      119 |                     src: '/test/src',
      120 |                     style: {

      at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1652:13)
      at ShallowWrapper.props (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1175:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/unit-tests/components/ImageDisplay.component.test.tsx:117:44)
```

I understand that the `expect` is failing since it's executing immediately without waiting for the `image.onload` to finish and hence it's unable to find the `img` element.

Is there a way to test the image events and the component behaviour? Really appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an waitForComponentToPaint function to wait until the entire component is fully painted.

```
const waitTimeout = (time = 0) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));

const waitForComponentToPaint = async (wrapper, time = 0) => {
  await act(async () => {
    await waitTimeout(time);
    wrapper.update();
  });
};
```

And then you can use like that:

```
it('should set image props', async () => {
    await waitForComponentToPaint(wrapper)
    expect(wrapper.find('img').props()).toEqual({
        alt: 'test_alt',
        src: '/test/src',
        style: {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am getting the same error. Is there a way to mock the `image.onload` in tests?

Comment: Do you need to remove the useEffect mock, cause this way, it will never set the setShowImage as true.

Comment: No, the useEffect mock should be there, as it calls `setDimension` synchronously and then `setShowImage` on image load or error.

Comment: With the mock, the default behavior of useEffect will be overwritten and both functions will not be called.